# Show that the set $ [-1, \infty )$ has cardinality $ c \ \ $

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the set $ [-1, \infty )$ has cardinality of the continuum. Draw the **bijection.**

**Answer:**
If I consider the map $ f: [-1, \infty ) \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty) $ by $ f(x)=\log(1+x) $.

This is one-one  and onto.

Hence the proof.

But I have doubts using $ f(x)= \log(1+x) $ because it is not defined at $ x=-1 $.

**Any help is there ?**

Comment: Your $f$ is a bijection $(-1,\infty) \to (-\infty,\infty)$. In order to get a bijection $[-1,\infty) \to (-1,\infty)$, you can send $1/n \mapsto 1/(n+1)$ for integers $n \ge 1$, and send $-1 \mapsto 1$, while leaving everything else fixed. There might be a simpler way to construct a bijection directly from $[-1,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$ instead of composing two bijections.

Comment: Your $f$ is undefined at $x=-1$.

Comment: You can't get a continuous bijection between the two.

Comment: how can i draw the bijection

Comment: @angryavian What you wrote is an answer. Why don't you post it as such?

Comment: Your propositsion works with $(-1,\infty)$. @angryavian gave you a desired bijection.

Comment: i said in the question that I have to draw bijection

Comment: We'd like to know what that means. Defining an explicit mapping is much more desirable than "drawing". Perhaps, they are synonyms.